# user lacks privilege or object not found: XXXX

Tags: java, database

i am having an this error when i'm trying to put data into database
this is my signup function

```
void signup() throws SQLException {

          String name=signupForm.getSignUpName().getText();
           String password=new String(signupForm.getSignUpPassword().getPassword());


          System.out.println(name);
          System.out.println(password);
        conn= getConnection();
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        query = "INSERT INTO student_signup(student_password) VALUES"+"("+password+")";
          System.out.println(name);

                     rs=statement.executeQuery(query);



            statement.close();
            conn.close();

}
```

for example if i enter qweqweqwe as password then errror would be like 
user lacks privilege or object not found: qweqweqwe

table name as well as field name is exact as in query so no problem there

the full error is this :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or
>   object not found: QWEQW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in SQL should be limited by single quotes, so you should update your query as follows:

```java
query = "INSERT INTO student_signup(student_password) VALUES"+"('"+password+"')";
```

Actually, creating a query by concatenating strings is a very bad idea, because your code could be prone to SQL injections. A better way to do the same would be to use a prepared statement:

```java
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO student_signup(student_password) VALUES(?)");
statement.setString(1, password);
statement.execute();
```